# Need to call a service inside of a condtional which is inside of a subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

So inside of my ngOnInit i am getting some object from angular firestore, I then need to carry out some logic on the returned value, revolving around the last updated date. If last updated is today then I want to then re update the last updated to today with the timestamp.

This works fine, however when i call this.planService.updatePlan(), it causes the code to execute twice and everything executes twice within the subscription. I assume this is because the subscription hasnt 'finished' yet and is causing the if statement to reevaluate.

I am fairly new to rxJs so i guess the problem lies in my lack of understanding of the order of operations.

So how can I call my planService.updatePlan inside the else block that it currenlty is without causing the repeat execution ?

Any help would be appreciated !!

```
  ngOnInit() {  
    this.subscription = this.planService.getActivePlan()
      .subscribe(result => {     

        if(result[0].excludeWeekends){
          if(moment().day() == 0 || moment().day() == 6){
            this.lockPlan = true;
          }else {
            this.lockPlan = false;
          }        
        }

        let testForSameLastUpdated  = moment(moment(result[0].lastUpdated).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        let testForSameToday = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

        if(!moment(testForSameLastUpdated).isSame(testForSameToday)){
          console.log("Not updated today");
          result[0].variableDailyLeft = result[0]['dailyleft']; 

          this.updatePlanData(result[0]);

        }else{
          console.log("Plan has been updated today");               
          result[0].lastUpdated = this.today.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS');

          this.planService.updatePlan(result[0]['id'], result[0])
          .then( res => {
            this.activePlan = result[0];
            }
          )
        }            
      });
  }
```

My getActivePlan() code is as follows

```
    getActivePlan(){  
        this.active$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
        return this.plan$ = this.active$.pipe(
            switchMap(active => 
                this.db
                .collection<Plan>('plans', ref => ref.where
                ('activePlan', '==' ,active))                  
                .valueChanges({idField:'id'})
            ),
        );

    }
```

And my updatePlan()

```
    updatePlan(id, plan){
        return this.db.collection('plans').doc(id).set(plan);
    }
```

Comment: could you please provide `getActivePlan` code?

Comment: I guess you are pushing new value to the observable returned from `getActivePlan()` function inside the `updatePlan()` function. Could you please provide the code for both these functions?

Comment: Have edited to show both of these

Comment: There is something architecturally wrong here. You are pushing to an observable in the callback to the same observable. So you creating an unintentional loop. You need to modify your code so that you don't depend on the observable to update itself.

Comment: The problem is that you have several problems. Overall you're polluting RxJS's reactive structure with imperative logic (conditionals, variables...) and promises that you haven't converted to observables. ```getActivePlan()``` in particular is overcomplicated and shows you haven't grasped RxJS fundamentals yet. ReactiveX is hard for OO programmers to get at first, but the high learning curve is worth it. Keep working at it. [Learn RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) is a great resource along with many RxJS and Angular tutorials online.

Comment: Look at things you can do with ```filter()```, ```map()```, and ```switchMap()``` / ```mergeMap()```. Don't be afraid to break into several streams filtered to handle different conditions, before merging them back together later.

Comment: Ok thanks, thought that would be the case. I shall have to read up more on RxJS